# PHP SQL Query Join 3 tables through a field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables. 
Are 3 tables have a field called "hobbyid" and I need to join the 3 in an sql query.

What I have right now is one table:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE username='".$username."' ");
```

Here is same sample structure:

```
table1

+----+----------+----------+---------+
| id | username | password | hobbyid |
+----+----------+----------+---------+

table2

+----+----------+---------------+---------+
| id | username | somethingelse | hobbyid |
+----+----------+---------------+---------+

table3

+----+----------+-----------+---------+
| id | username | something | hobbyid |
+----+----------+-----------+---------+
```

How can I join the 3 tables so I can get data from all 3?

Comment: What do you expect? How should the fields with different names merge?

Comment: I need to be able to have access on all fields on the 3 tables by joining them using the hobbyid field present in the 3 tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even practically there is no need to create 3 tables but still if you feel that it is required then you can use union all (if you need all duplicate value also) or union if you need distinct value. But for this there should be same columns in all tables.

Use below query if you need all data from all 3 tables-

```
select * from table1 where username='abc'
union all 
select * from table2 where username='abc'
union all 
select * from table3 where username='abc';
```

If you want only common data based on hobbyid then use below query-

```
select a.username,a.password,a.hobbyid,b.somethingelse,c.something from table1 a join table2 b on a.hobbyid=b.hobbyid join table 3 c on a.hobbyid=c.hobbyid where a.username='abc';
```

If both are not suitable for you then please eleborate your requirement.

Comment: i think while using union the tables need  to have same columns :?

Comment: not same columns but same no of columns...in this case something and somethingelse will go to password column...you can say it is not practical but may worked for someone in special condition.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do the trick?

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, username, hobbyid FROM table1 WHERE username='".$username."'
UNION ALL (SELECT id, username, hobbyid FROM table2 WHERE username='".$username."')
UNION ALL (SELECT id, username, hobbyid FROM table3 WHERE username='".$username."')");
```

This will join only *id, username, hobbyid* - all other fields will be ommited. If you want to perserve them you will have to use JOIN-s.

Comment: I might need joins as I need to access other fields too and I only need to verify the username on table1.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table1 a, table2 b, table3 c
where a.username= '$username' and b.username= '$username' and c.username='$username'
//(or)

//if you want to get the data having same username from tabls
select * from table1 a
inner join table2 b on a.username= b.username
inner join course c on b.username= c.username
```